# Set cookie sameSite in Play framework 2.3

Tags: java, cookies, playframework, session-cookies, samesite

play.mvc.Http.Cookie objects in Play 2.3 do not support setting the sameSite attribute. 
Is there a workaround to manually set it (with Java) in the PLAY_SESSION cookie in Play 2.3?

...and no, it can't update Play to a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use `Set-Cookie` directly. I just tested it.

The reason is due to [this code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.7/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/server/netty/NettyResultStreamer.scala#L171-L179) which uses [this other code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.7/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala#L745-L762).

If we use `SameSite=None` anywhere in the value of the `Set-Cookie` header, then Play Framework mistakenly see that as the beginning of another cookie !

---

What about using the standard header `Set-Cookie`?

```http
Set-Cookie: flavor=choco; SameSite=None; Secure
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite